# SQL - How do i output string with numbers in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to get a number 5000.1 and divide it by 1000 before adding an "F" infront of it.

How do i do this? I tried and failed this:

```
select "F" + round ( acq.store_size_net / 1000, 0) from acq
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Eric - Why does it matter what database they are using? Surely more important to know what RDBMS they are using?

Comment: @Martin - by "database", I meant RDBMS vendor.  Probably should have been more clear with my terminology.

Comment: @Eric - I know I was just being pedantic. For some reason that particular misuse of terminology irritates me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your missing the cast of the number to a text data type

Without knowing the exact dialect of sql you're using im gonna hazard a guess at ms-sql

```
select 'F' + cast(cast(round ( 5000.1 / 1000, 0)as int) as nvarchar(50))
```

produces output
`F5`

Answer (score 1):

This will work in Oracle :

```
 select 'F' || round (acq.store_size_net / 1000, 0) from acq
```